# C# Binary Search Tree implementation

Tags: c#, algorithm, .net, api, binary-search-tree

I have implemented a Binary Search Tree and would really appreciate it if someone could take time to check it and give me feedback.
I try to keep my code clear and simple.

Is it readable?
Is the API of constructors well-designed?
Did I handle the nullable fields of the tree and iterators well?

Please be as strict as possible with me.

**Code:**

[GitHub](https://github.com/purplewawe/Learning-CS/blob/master/Alogithms%20and%20Data%20Structures/DataStructures/BinarySearchTree/BinarySearchTree.cs)

TreeNode code:

```
public class TreeNode
{
    public readonly T Value;

    public TreeNode? LeftLeaf;
    public TreeNode? RightLeaf;

    public TreeNode(T elem)
    {
        Value = elem;
        LeftLeaf = null;
        RightLeaf = null;
    }

    public TreeNode(T elem, TreeNode? left, TreeNode? right) : this(elem)
    {
        LeftLeaf = left;
        RightLeaf = right;
    }
}
```

BinarySearchTree fields, properties and constructors:

```
public class BinarySearchTree<T> : ICollection<T>
where T : IComparable<T>
{   
    //TreeNode code 
    //{
    //    see it above
    //}

    public BinarySearchTree()
    {
        Root = null;
        _size = 0;
    }

    public BinarySearchTree(T firstElem)
    {
        Root = new TreeNode(firstElem);
        _size = 0;
    }

    public BinarySearchTree(
        T[] arry, 
        BinarySearchTreeSortOrder order = BinarySearchTreeSortOrder.Ascdending
        Comparer<T>? comparer = null)
    {
        if (arry == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(arry));
        if (arry.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(arry));

        this.Root = new TreeNode(arry[0]);
        this._size = 1;
    
        _order = order;
        _comparer = comparer;
    }

    // properties
    public int Count => _size;
    public bool IsReadOnly => false;

    // methods
    // Add()    
    // Compare()    
    // Clear()    
    // Contains()     
    // CopyTo()    
    // Min()    
    // Max()    
    // Remove()
    // enumerators section
}
```

Add method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds an element to the Binary Search Tree in O(n) worse case 
/// and O(log(n)) average case.
/// If the given element already exists in the tree adds a duplicate.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="item"></param>
public void Add(T item)
{
    Add(Root, item);
    _size++;
}

// returns the subtree of the given TreeNode that contains new item.
private TreeNode Add(TreeNode? addRoot, T item)
{
    if (addRoot == null) addRoot = new TreeNode(item);
    else
    {
        var cmp = this.Compare(item, addRoot.Value);
        if (cmp <= 0) addRoot.LeftLeaf = Add(addRoot.LeftLeaf, item);
        if (cmp > 0) addRoot.RightLeaf = Add(addRoot.RightLeaf, item);
    }

    return addRoot;
}
```

Compare method:

```
private int Compare(T item1, T item2)
{
    int compVal = this._comparer?.Compare(item1, item2) ?? item1.CompareTo(item2);
    return compVal * (_order == BinarySearchTreeSortOrder.Ascdending ? 1 : -1);
}
```

Clear method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Clears the BinarySearchTree. Assigns null to the root element.
/// </summary>
public void Clear()
{
    this.Root = null;
    this._size = 0;
}
```

Contains method:

```
/// <summary>
/// If BinarySearchTree contains the specified element returns true 
///and false otherwise.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="item"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public bool Contains(T item)
{
    var node = Root;
    while (node != null)
    {
        int cmp = this.Compare(item, node.Value);
        if (cmp < 0) node = node.LeftLeaf;
        else if (cmp > 0) node = node.RightLeaf;
        else return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

CopyTo method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Copies elements of the BinarySearchTree to the specified array in sorted order.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="array"></param>
/// <param name="arrayIndex"></param>
public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
{
    using (var enumerator = this.GetEnumerator(Traversal.InOrder))
    {
        int i = arrayIndex;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) enumerator.MoveNext();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext()) array[i++] = enumerator.Current;
    }
}
```

Min method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Extracts the minimal element of the BinarySearchTree in O(1) time.
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
/// <exception cref="NullReferenceException"></exception>
public T Min()
{
    if (Root == null) throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(Root));
    return this.Min(Root).Value;
}

private TreeNode Min(TreeNode minRoot)
{
    while (minRoot.LeftLeaf != null) minRoot = minRoot.LeftLeaf;
    return minRoot;
}
```

Max method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Extracts the biggest element of the BinarySearchTree in O(n) worse case 
///and O(log(n)) average case.
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
/// <exception cref="NullReferenceException"></exception>
public T Max()
{
    if (Root == null) throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(Root));
    return this.Max(this.Root).Value;
}

private TreeNode Max(TreeNode maxRoot)
{
    while (maxRoot.RightLeaf != null) maxRoot = maxRoot.RightLeaf;
    return maxRoot;
}
```

Remove method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Performs removal of specified item from the BinarySearchTree in O(n) worse
/// case and O(log(n)) average case.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="item"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public bool Remove(T item)
{
    if (!Contains(item)) return false;

    Root = Remove(Root, item);
    _size--;
    return true;
}

private TreeNode? Remove(TreeNode? removeRoot, T item)
{
    if (removeRoot == null) return null;

    var cmp = this.Compare(item, removeRoot.Value);

    if (cmp == 1) removeRoot.RightLeaf = Remove(removeRoot.RightLeaf, item);
    else if (cmp == -1) removeRoot.LeftLeaf = Remove(removeRoot.LeftLeaf, item);
    else
    {
        if (removeRoot.LeftLeaf == null && removeRoot.RightLeaf == null) 
            return null;
        //there are 2 leafs
        if (removeRoot.RightLeaf != null && removeRoot.LeftLeaf != null)
        {
            //find min, replace root with the min and remove min
            var rightMin = Min(removeRoot.RightLeaf);

            rightMin.RightLeaf = Remove(removeRoot.RightLeaf, rightMin.Value);
            rightMin.LeftLeaf = removeRoot.LeftLeaf;
            return rightMin;
        }

        return removeRoot.LeftLeaf ?? removeRoot.RightLeaf;
    }

    return removeRoot;
}
```

GetEnumerator method:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator(Traversal.InOrder);

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator(Traversal.InOrder);

public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator(Traversal traversal)
{
    switch (traversal)
    {
        case Traversal.InOrder: return new InOrderIterator(this);
        case Traversal.PreOrder: return new PreOrderIterator(this);
        case Traversal.LevelOrder: return new LevelOrderIterator(this);
    }

    return new InOrderIterator(this);
}
```

InOrderEnumerator:

```
private class InOrderIterator : IEnumerator<T>
{

    private readonly BinarySearchTree<T> _bst;

    private readonly Stack<TreeNode>  _stack = new();

    private TreeNode _trav;
    private TreeNode _current;

    public InOrderIterator(BinarySearchTree<T> bst)
    {
        this._bst = bst ?? throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(bst));
        _trav = bst.Root ?? throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(bst.Root));
        _stack.Push(bst.Root);
        _current = bst.Root;
    }
    
    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (_stack.Count == 0) return false;

        while (_trav.LeftLeaf != null)
        {
            _stack.Push(_trav.LeftLeaf);
            _trav = _trav.LeftLeaf;
        }

        _current = _stack.Pop();

        if (_current.RightLeaf != null)
        {
            _stack.Push(_current.RightLeaf);
            _trav = _current.RightLeaf;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        if (_bst.Root != null)
        {
            _trav = _bst.Root;
            _stack.Push(_bst.Root);
        }
    }

    public T Current => _current.Value;

    object IEnumerator.Current => Current;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        /*throw new NotImplementedException();*/
    }
}
```

PreOrderEnumerator:

```
private class PreOrderIterator : IEnumerator<T>
{
    private readonly BinarySearchTree<T> _bst;

    private readonly Stack<TreeNode> _stack = new();

    private TreeNode _current;

    public PreOrderIterator(BinarySearchTree<T> bst)
    {
        this._bst = bst ?? throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(bst));
        _current = bst.Root ?? throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(bst.Root));
        _stack.Push(bst.Root);
    }
    public T Current => _current.Value;

    object IEnumerator.Current => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (_stack.Count == 0) return false;
        _current = _stack.Pop();
        if (_current.RightLeaf != null) _stack.Push(_current.RightLeaf);
        if (_current.LeftLeaf != null) _stack.Push(_current.LeftLeaf);
        return true;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        if (_bst.Root != null)
        {
            _stack.Clear();
            _stack.Push(_bst.Root);
        }
    }
}
```

LevelOrderEnumerator:

```
private class LevelOrderIterator : IEnumerator<T>
{
    private BinarySearchTree<T> _bst;

    private Queue<TreeNode> _queue = new();

    private TreeNode _current;

    public LevelOrderIterator(BinarySearchTree<T> bst)
    {
        this._bst = bst ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bst));

        if (bst.Root == null) 
            throw new NullReferenceException($"{nameof(bst.Root)} is null.");

        _current = new TreeNode(bst.Root.Value, 
                                bst.Root.LeftLeaf,
                                bst.Root.RightLeaf);

        _queue.Enqueue(bst.Root);
    }
    
    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (_queue.Count == 0) return false;

        _current = _queue.Dequeue();

        if (_current.LeftLeaf != null) _queue.Enqueue(_current.LeftLeaf);
        if (_current.RightLeaf != null) _queue.Enqueue(_current.RightLeaf);

        return true;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        if (_bst.Root != null)
        {
            _queue.Clear();
            _queue.Enqueue(_bst.Root);
        }
    }

    public T Current => _current.Value;

    object IEnumerator.Current => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Declared outside of the BinarySearchTree

Traversal type:

```
public enum Traversal
{
    InOrder,
    PreOrder,
    LevelOrder,
    PostOrder
}
```

Sort order:

```
public enum BinarySearchTreeSortOrder
{
    Ascdending,
    Descending
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My apologies that I do not have enough time to review the entire code, but I do have remarks about the stuff towards the top.

**Class TreeNode**

I would alter the constructors differently than what you show.  What you have is nice enough, and I do struggle on whether this is my personal preference or a better design, so I offer this an an alternative.

```
public TreeNode(T elem) : this(elem, null, null)
{ }

public TreeNode(T elem, TreeNode? left, TreeNode? right)
{
    Value = elem;
    LeftLeaf = left;
    RightLeaf = right;
}
```

**BinarySearchTree contructor #2**

```
public BinarySearchTree(T firstElem)
{
    Root = new TreeNode(firstElem);
    _size = 0;
}
```

Should that be `_size = 1;` ???

**BinarySearchTree contructor #3**

What you have:

```
public BinarySearchTree(
    T[] arry, 
    BinarySearchTreeSortOrder order = BinarySearchTreeSortOrder.Ascdending
    Comparer<T>? comparer = null)
{
    if (arry == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(arry));
    if (arry.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(arry));

    this.Root = new TreeNode(arry[0]);
    this._size = 1;

    _order = order;
    _comparer = comparer;
}
```

Observations:

You restrict the input to be an **array** of T.  It would be more flexible is you allowed it to be `IList<T>`.  It would be even more flexible if you allowed it to be `IEnumerable<T>`.  If you do use enumerable, then you also have to change checks for `Length` or grabbing index `[0]`.

You seem to only set the Root with the first element in the array, and then do nothing with remaining elements.  What if someone passes in a 5 element collection?

Here's a short (imperfect) stub demonstrating using enumerable input:

```
public BinarySearchTree(
    IEnumerable<T> elements, 
    BinarySearchTreeSortOrder order = BinarySearchTreeSortOrder.Ascdending
    Comparer<T>? comparer = null)
{
    if (elements == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(elements));
    if (!elements.Any()) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(elements));

    this.Root = new TreeNode(elements.First());
    this._size = 1;

    _order = order;
    _comparer = comparer;

    // To process more elements, use something like:
    foreach (var element in elements.Skip(1))
    {
         // do something
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback!

Comment: (If not learning just C#, but OO design&coding: Well done!)

Answer (score 2):

A pity you didn't present the *class summary* the GitHub repository contains.
One thing I'd move up there is *the enumeration of methods* presented above at the end of `class BinarySearchTree<T>`.
Pretty much constituting the interface, which I consider neat
(but for the mention of inconsequential internal detail:
 storage - not presented above
 existence&handling of `Root`).
(Rick Davin has an [excellent point](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/278279/93149) about "the powerful" constructor.
 Where there is a non-negligible chance of the elements of the enumerable being ordered, one might better adapt the order of processing.)

Possible changes include `PostOrderIterator` and *reverse traversals*.
The latter would allow to ignore the difference between ascending and descending everywhere but in the iterators. Having an array of children might help avoiding *code duplication*.

What you call *leaf* is conventionally called *child* -
a *leaf* is a node with no children.
(`Ascdending` contains a typo - less of an issue given *rename*.
 And among the cases worse than the average, *worst* usually gets mentioned.)

The summary of `T Min()` specifies `O(1) time` -
the implementation doesn't support that (see `T Max()`).
(Empty SGML tags can be denoted `<returns/>`.)

It should be possible to avoid the call to `Contains()` in `bool Remove(T item)` -
nothing that came to my mind would be as readable.